# MySQL SUM, JOIN and GROUP BY... proper structure

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-4

I'm having a bit of trouble navigating through my tables and structuring my SQL statement to GROUP BY team_id (using Laravel 4 Fluent). If I remove the GROUP BY I am getting the total steps for each user. But what I need is the total steps for each team.

**SQL Statement:**

```
SELECT  `user_challenge`.`team_id` ,  `teams`.`name` , (
SELECT SUM( activities.steps ) 
FROM activities
WHERE activities.user_id = users.id
AND activities.created_at <=  '2013-11-30 15:32:45'
AND activities.date >=  '2013-10-01 15:32:45'
AND activities.date <=  '2013-11-30 15:32:45'
) AS steps
FROM  `user_challenge` 
INNER JOIN  `users` ON  `user_challenge`.`user_id` =  `users`.`id` 
INNER JOIN  `teams` ON  `user_challenge`.`team_id` =  `teams`.`id` 
WHERE  `user_challenge`.`challenge_id` =2
AND  `user_challenge`.`team_id` IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY  `user_challenge`.`team_id`
```

**PHP (Laravel) if it helps:**

```
$subquery = "(SELECT SUM(activities.$type) FROM activities WHERE activities.user_id = users.id AND activities.created_at <= '". $challenge->end_date ."' AND activities.date >= '". $challenge->start_date ."' AND activities.date <= '". $challenge->end_date ."') as $type";
$teams = DB::table('user_challenge')
    ->where('user_challenge.challenge_id', $challenge->id)
    ->whereNotNull('user_challenge.team_id')
    ->join('users','user_challenge.user_id','=','users.id')
    ->join('teams','user_challenge.team_id','=','teams.id')
    ->select('user_challenge.team_id', 'teams.name',DB::raw($subquery))
    ->groupBy('user_challenge.team_id')
    ->get();
```

**Output with GROUP BY:**

```
team_id, name, steps
1, Team 1, null
```

**Output without GROUP BY:**

```
team_id, name, steps
1, Team 1, null
1, Team 1, 13000
1, Team 1, 10000
```

**Desired Output:**

```
team_id, name, steps
1, Team 1, 23000
```

[image: tables]

Comment: if you dont need a laravel-fluent specific solution you dont need the laravel tags included on your question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use group by in a single query instead of nesting (the way you have it). 
Here's one way to approach it:

```
SELECT  `user_challenge`.`team_id` ,  `teams`.`name` , SUM(`userStepSum`) as `TeamStepSum`
FROM  `user_challenge` 
INNER JOIN  `users` ON  `user_challenge`.`user_id` =  `users`.`id` 
INNER JOIN  `teams` ON  `user_challenge`.`team_id` =  `teams`.`id` 
INNER JOIN 
(
SELECT activities.user_id, SUM( activities.steps ) as `userStepSum`
FROM activities
where 
AND activities.created_at <=  '2013-11-30 15:32:45'
AND activities.date >=  '2013-10-01 15:32:45'
AND activities.date <=  '2013-11-30 15:32:45'
GROUP BY `activities`.`user_id`
) `user_steps` on `user_steps`.`user_id` = `user_challenge`.`user_id`
WHERE  `user_challenge`.`challenge_id` =2
AND  `user_challenge`.`team_id` IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY  `user_challenge`.`team_id`
```

You could also just join to activities directly. Good luck.